# Null check operator used on a null value FirebaseAuth instance

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this exception when trying to pull data from Firebase Storage using a bang(!) on my comment likes list and currentUser!uid.

```
color: eachCommentInfo.commentLikesList!
                                .contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                ? Colors.red
                                : Colors.white,
```

I don't know if there's a better way to do this so I it won't throw the exception Null check operator used on a null value.

I tried putting it into a var then using it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tried like this;

```
color: eachCommentInfo.commentLikesList != null &&
        eachCommentInfo.commentLikesList!
            .contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    ? Colors.red
    : Colors.white,
```

Comment: Can you check as the correct answer to my answer?